# Playing video in Facebook NewsFeed

Tags: facebook-opengraph

Would like to play video in Facebook.
Here's my page. The video is playing well when you visit the site http://sefid.co.ke

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#">
  <head>
    <title>The Rock (1996)</title>
<meta property="og:title" content="#video.title#"> 
<meta property="og:description" content="#video.description#">
<meta property="og:type" content="video">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://sefid.co.ke/jwplayer/preview.jpg">
<meta property="og:video" content="http://sefid.co.ke/jwplayer/player.swf?embedCode=#url.watch#&autoplay=1&keepembedCode=true">
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash">
<meta property="og:video:width" content="470">
<meta property="og:video:height" content="320">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="AOPA">

</head>
<body>
<object classid='clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000' width='470' height='320' id='single1' name='single1'>
<param name='movie' value='/jwplayer/player.swf'>
<param name='allowfullscreen' value='true'>
<param name='allowscriptaccess' value='always'>
<param name='wmode' value='transparent'>
<param name='flashvars' value='file=http://sefid.co.ke/jwplayer/player.swf?file=%2Fjwplayer%2Fvideo.mp4'>
<embed
  id='single2'
  name='single2'
  src='/jwplayer/player.swf'
  width='470'
  height='320'
  bgcolor='#000000'
  allowscriptaccess='always'
  allowfullscreen='true'
  flashvars='file=/jwplayer/video.mp4'
/>
</object>
</body>

</html>
```

What might be problem?

Kindly assist.

I appreciate

Roger

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xml:lang="en" lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://xxxxx.XXXX.www/wwwwww/XXXXX.jpg" />
<meta property="og:video" content="http://www.wwwww.www/wwwww/wwwwwwww.swf" />
<meta content="video" name="medium" />
<meta content="400" property="og:video:height" />
<meta content="400" property="og:video:width" />
<meta content="application/x-shockwave-flash" property="og:video:type" />

</head>
<body>
<div id="live" style="display:block;width:400px;height:400px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Eduard. Unfortunately it still doesn't work. Do you have a page where it's working. Maybe I could derive something from the source code